# Use of the gap and first feasible options with Symphony or CBC in R

Tags: r, linear-programming

The linear programs I am trying to solve are often too demanding to wait for an optimal solution, so I am evaluating the use of the 'gap' and 'first feasible' options.
Please correct me if I am wrong: asking for the 'first feasible' solution may potentially give a very far from optimal objective, because it only requires that the constraints are satisfied.
On the other hand, setting a maximal 'gap' should guarantee that one is not too far from optimality, but could still result in a very long execution time.

Here is some example code that I used to test this.
In essence, you have `N_products` products, each sold by `N_vendors` distinct vendors, at a given price. You want to choose from which vendor to buy each product, so that the total price is mimimal, that you buy all products (once), and that you use no more than `max_N_vendors` vendors.
[The problem I am solving is similar in the sense that it has a large number of binary variables; but it has some continuous variables, too, which are in fact the ones that make up the objective.
I am hoping this difference does not make this example irrelevant, but please tell me if you think it is the case].

```
# Load required packages
require(Rsymphony)
require(rcbc)
require(Matrix)

# User parameters
N_products = 500
N_vendors = 4
max_N_vendors = 2
use_first_feasible = FALSE
gap = 0

# Simulate data
set.seed(989002)
N <- N_vendors * N_products
d <- expand.grid("product" = 1:N_products, "vendor" = 1:N_vendors)
d["price"] <- runif(N, 10, 100)
d["ID"] <- 1:N

# Make the objective vector
obj <- c(d[["price"]], rep(0, N_vendors))

# Make the constraints matrix
constr <- NULL
dir <- NULL
rhs <- NULL
# 1. All products must be purchased (once)
constr.products <- cbind(xtabs(~ product + ID, d, sparse = T), Matrix(0, nrow = N_products, ncol = N_vendors, sparse = T))
dir <- c(dir, rep("==", N_products))
rhs <- c(rhs, rep(1, N_products))
# 2. Impose max number of vendors
constr.vendors <- cbind(xtabs(~ vendor + ID, d, sparse = T), .sparseDiagonal(N_vendors, -N_products))
constr.vendors <- rbind(constr.vendors, c(rep(0, N), rep(1, N_vendors)))
dir <- c(dir, rep("<=", N_vendors + 1))
rhs <- c(rhs, rep(0, N_vendors), max_N_vendors)

constr <- rbind(constr.products, constr.vendors)

# Solve by Rsymphony
set.seed(989003)
time_Rsymphony <- system.time( lpout_Rsymphony <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj = obj, mat = constr, dir = dir, rhs = rhs, types = "B", max = FALSE, verbosity = -2, first_feasible = use_first_feasible, gap_limit = ifelse(gap == 0, -1, gap)) )

cat("\nRsymphony time = ", time_Rsymphony)
cat("\nRsymphony objective = ", lpout_Rsymphony$objval)

d_Rsymphony_solution <- d[which(lpout_Rsymphony$solution[1:N] == 1),]

# Solve by rcbc
# Convert formats
row_lb <- NULL
row_ub <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(rhs)) {
  if (dir[i] == "==") {row_lb <- c(row_lb, rhs[i]); row_ub <- c(row_ub, rhs[i])}
  if (dir[i] == ">=") {row_lb <- c(row_lb, rhs[i]); row_ub <- c(row_ub, Inf)}
  if (dir[i] == "<=") {row_lb <- c(row_lb, -Inf); row_ub <- c(row_ub, rhs[i])}
}
col_lb <- rep(0, N + N_vendors)
col_ub <- rep(1, N + N_vendors)

set.seed(989004)
time_rcbc <- system.time( lpout_rcbc <- cbc_solve(obj = obj, mat = constr, row_lb = row_lb, row_ub = row_ub, col_lb = col_lb, col_ub = col_ub, is_integer = rep(TRUE, N + N_vendors), max = FALSE, cbc_args = list(log = "0", maxso = ifelse(use_first_feasible, "1", "0"), ratio = ifelse(gap == 0, "0", as.character(gap))) ) )

cat("\nrcbc time = ", time_rcbc)
cat("\nrcbc objective = ", lpout_rcbc$objective_value)

d_rcbc_solution <- d[which(lpout_rcbc$column_solution[1:N] == 1),]
```

When I run this with:

```
use_first_feasible = FALSE
gap = 0
```

This is what I get:

```
Rsymphony time =  2.64 0 2.69 NA NA
Rsymphony objective =  19645.4
rcbc time =  15.99 0.24 16.45 NA NA
rcbc objective =  19645.4
```

If I ask for the first feasible:

```
use_first_feasible = TRUE
gap = 0
```

I get this instead (but not always!*):

```
Rsymphony time =  1.59 0 1.59 NA NA
Rsymphony objective =  19832.68
rcbc time =  0.03 0.01 0.05 NA NA
rcbc objective =  19645.4
```

Several things I don't understand, on which I'd please like to hear your advice:

- why CBC becomes *much* faster than Symphony when I ask for the first feasible solution, and is instead markedly slower when not doing so
- *why the result for Symphony changes when I re-run the same code (as if the solver were using some random seed; but I set the seed indeed to have reproducible results, so...?)
- why CBC seems to give quite consistently the absolute optimal solution even when asking for the first feasible, and much faster than it does when not asking for the first feasible. Coincidence? Or is there something about CBC that steers it closer to the absolute optimal solution from the beginning, so it's safer to use the first feasible?

As for the gap, I tried several different values (with `use_first_feasible = FALSE`), but it never made a difference to the *CBC* result, except that CBC again became as fast or much faster than Symphony, more markedly so when the gap was larger.

```
use_first_feasible = FALSE
gap = 0.1

Rsymphony time =  3.06 0.01 3.08 NA NA
Rsymphony objective =  19645.4
rcbc time =  2.8 0.04 2.82 NA NA
rcbc objective =  19645.4

use_first_feasible = FALSE
gap = 100

Rsymphony time =  2.2 0.02 2.22 NA NA
Rsymphony objective =  20449.97
rcbc time =  0.06 0 0.06 NA NA
rcbc objective =  19645.4

use_first_feasible = FALSE
gap = 1000000

Rsymphony time =  2.14 0.02 2.14 NA NA
Rsymphony objective =  20449.97
rcbc time =  0.05 0 0.05 NA NA
rcbc objective =  19645.4
```

I am also quite lost as to what the 'gap' itself means, numerically.
This is what the `rcbc` documentation says:

> Optimality gap for solving the problem. The optimization process will stop when the performance of the best found solution is near enough to optimality based on this parameter. For example, a value of 0.15 means that the optimization process will stop when the best found solution is within 15 Defaults to "0", such that only an optimal solution is returned.

And this for `Rsymphony`:

> when the gap between the lower and the upper bound reaches this point, the solution process will stop and the best solution found to that point will be returned, -1 (default) means no gap limit.

I confess that I do not understand what either of these means.
When I run the solvers letting them print the logs of what is happening, I do see these upper and lower bounds, and for CBC it even gives you the objective that would be expected for an absolute optimal solution, but then how the current objective, gap and minimal possible objective are related, that I do not get.

**Very practically, how would I set the gap if I wanted my objective to be within, say, 10% of absolute optimality? Is that even possible?**

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: "Very practically, how would I set the gap if I wanted my objective to be within, say, 10% of absolute optimality? Is that even possible?" If they use a relative gap (instead of an absolute gap), the use gap=0.1.

Comment: "f they use a relative gap (instead of an absolute gap)" - that's precisely the problem, I don't get, from the description they give in the documentation, what this 'gap' means to them :( Maybe I should go back to the original literature of these solvers, but the R implementations might have their own special way of handling this gap, so... Perhaps the only way is trial and error.

Comment: This sort of optimization problems are typically very hard to solve. Thus, I would advice to use more powerful programs like CPLEX or Gurobi, but they both are commercial and not free, unless you are an academic or student.

Comment: @PaulSmith : thanks; it would not be a problem to use a commercial solver, my company would support that. We considered CPLEX, and asked for a trial license, because of course we wanted to know if the performance was significantly better, before committing to a paid version. It never worked, there was always a problem with the download or something else, so we gave up. Besides, solving this kind of problems is not really our core business, so perhaps we can do with some free linear program solver for now. I just wanted to try and get the best out of those.

Comment: There is the setting of "gap_limit" which in the documentation says:
when the gap between the lower and the upper bound reaches this point, the solution
process will stop and the best solution found to that point will be returned,
-1 (default) means no gap limit.